# Can I roll a College 529 education savings plan into a prepaid tuition plan?

Tags: united-states, college, 529-plan, tuition

I currently have college savings in a 529 plan (New Hampshire).  Recently, Texas started the [Texas Tuition Promise Fund](https://www.texastuitionpromisefund.com/) which is a prepaid college savings plan.  I would like to roll the money I have saved in the 529 and buy into the prepaid plan.  I have been searching but haven't found out if this is possible.  Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make a non-qualifying withdrawal from the 529 plan to then contribute to the Texas Tuition Promise Fund.

This would incur penalties on your withdrawals.